# What does it mean to "shear" an emulsion?

Tags: solubility, terminology, mixtures, viscosity

The following instructions are given for a preparation and I am wondering what it means to "shear an emulsion"?

> The water phase components and the oil phase components are each mixed
> in separate containers and filtered and the refractive index of each
> is measured. The refractive index of the water phase is adjusted to
> match the refractive index of the oil phase to within 0.0004 by
> addition of water or propylene glycol as required. The water phase is
> then slowly added to the oil phase at about 18.degree. C. with
> sufficient mixing to form a clear emulsion with minimum aeration. This
> emulsion is then **sheared** to form a clear gel with a viscosity of
> about 130,000 to 160,000 cP.

Comment: Check what is meant by shear forces in fluid mechanics. Hint: also see shear thickening and shear thinning.

Comment: While fluid mechanics is part of curricula in chemical engineering, note that engineering.se may offer a more receptive audience for this question.  See this [tag](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fluid-mechanics) as an example.

Comment: Search for "shear mixer" and you'll get a good idea eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-shear_mixer

Comment: You may also want to ask "why shear mix an emulsion?" Look into the Wikipedia article linked above.

Comment: An emulsion is made of small droplets in suspension in another liquid. Usually it is not stable. After some time, the two phases get separated. But if the mixture has been sheared, the emulsion is stable like milk and will not get separated.